# Unable to get value from core_config_data in M2

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

I am developing one extension in which I have one configuration form, after filling form when I click save button it successfully save the data in core_config_data, but to retrieve that data from table I need to flush M2 cache.
How can I get data from DB without flushing cache.

I am using below code to get data from DB:

```
$data   =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('user', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code :

So Inject a `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\CollectionFactory` in your class.

Then try:

```
$collection = $collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addScopeFilter($scope, $scopeId, $section)
```

The **$section** is the path,  **$scopeId** the id of the store or website depending on the scope & **$scope** is either "**stores**" or "**website**" or "**default**".